# Extjs - Get rowIndex of a selected row

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have been seleted a row, and now i want get rowIndex

maybe like

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].rowIndex
```

but it's undefined. How can i get it thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

how about this?

```
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
var row = grid.store.indexOf(selectedRecord);
```

you have to get the selected record of your grid and from that, you can search this record from your store and get its index.

Comment: That helped. Just wanted to add that you don't need .getSelectionModel()

Answer (score 4):

you can also get it from the `select` listener of the grid:

```
listeners: {
    select: function(selModel, record, index, options){
        alert(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grid.getCurrentPosition().row
```

Comment: almost! try `grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition()`

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 7 is:

```
console.log( 'Selection:', grid.getSelection() ) //One
console.log( 'Selection:', grid.getSelectable().getSelectedRecords() ) //Several
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need modify a column in a grid, you can use this code snapshot:

```
{text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'localizedStatus', width: 150,
     renderer: function(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
         return value;
     }
 },
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].get('id')
```